# Sampling substrings of a beaded necklace to determine the necklace composition

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, statistical-inference

I have a necklace composed of 100 beads, where each bead is one of 13 colors. If I am only able to look at one 4 bead sub-sequence at a time (connected, as they would be on the necklace) , how many such samplings are required until I am 99% sure I have seen all the 4 bead sub-sequences? Each bead color is guaranteed to be represented at least once.

Comment: It depends on the colours of the beads and your prior expectations about them. Did you mean to imply that the necklace is random? If so, with which distribution? Uniform over all admissible necklaces?

Comment: The necklace is not necessarily random. Consider it like a game where someone set it up for me to figure out.

Comment: But the positions of the $4$-bead sub-sequences that you see are uniformly random?

Comment: Yes, there are 100 beads, and I select the start position randomly, sorry.